# How can I customize logs for GCP App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, logging

I have an API running on GCP's App Engine, to which I send HTTP requests. I've been exploring the GCP Logs Explorer and it seems that every request is logged with some standard fields. I presume that is the case because I have not asked for that information to be logged in my code. The thing is, now that I know that is being logged regardless, I would like to add some fields, like the HTTP query and the response. I could find no useful help on GCP's instructions. Any help?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using [structured logging](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/structured-logging) as explained below:

> With structure logging, you can construct queries that search specific JSON paths and you can index specific fields in the log payload.

You can write structured logs to Logging in several ways:

- Using the Cloud Logging API to write log entries
- Using the Google Cloud CLI to write log entries
- Using the BindPlane service to ingest logs
- Supplying serialized JSON objects to the Logging agent

You may check this documentation on [writing structured logs](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/samples/logging-write-log-entry).

Here's a sample of a simplified JSON log entry:

```json
{
  "severity":"ERROR",
  "message":"There was an error in the application.",
  "httpRequest":{
    "requestMethod":"GET"
  },
  "times":"2020-10-12T07:20:50.52Z",
  "logging.googleapis.com/insertId":"42",
  "logging.googleapis.com/labels":{
    "user_label_1":"value_1",
    "user_label_2":"value_2"
  },
  "logging.googleapis.com/operation":{
    "id":"get_data",
    "producer":"github.com/MyProject/MyApplication",
     "first":"true"
  },
  "logging.googleapis.com/sourceLocation":{
    "file":"get_data.py",
    "line":"142",
    "function":"getData"
  },
  "logging.googleapis.com/spanId":"000000000000004a",
  "logging.googleapis.com/trace":"projects/my-projectid/traces/06796866738c859f2f19b7cfb3214824",
  "logging.googleapis.com/trace_sampled":false
}
```

And here's the result log entry:

```json
{
  "insertId": "42",
  "jsonPayload": {
    "message": "There was an error in the application",
    "times": "2019-10-12T07:20:50.52Z"
  },
  "httpRequest": {
    "requestMethod": "GET"
  },
  "resource": {
    "type": "k8s_container",
    "labels": {
      "container_name": "hello-app",
      "pod_name": "helloworld-gke-6cfd6f4599-9wff8",
      "project_id": "stackdriver-sandbox-92334288",
      "namespace_name": "default",
      "location": "us-west4",
      "cluster_name": "helloworld-gke"
    }
  },
  "timestamp": "2020-11-07T15:57:35.945508391Z",
  "severity": "ERROR",
  "labels": {
    "user_label_2": "value_2",
    "user_label_1": "value_1"
  },
  "logName": "projects/stackdriver-sandbox-92334288/logs/stdout",
  "operation": {
    "id": "get_data",
    "producer": "github.com/MyProject/MyApplication",
    "first": true
  },
  "trace": "projects/my-projectid/traces/06796866738c859f2f19b7cfb3214824",
  "sourceLocation": {
    "file": "get_data.py",
    "line": "142",
    "function": "getData"
  },
  "receiveTimestamp": "2020-11-07T15:57:42.411414059Z",
  "spanId": "000000000000004a"
}
```

Comment: Your answer is close. Show a complete example using the CLI or any supported language. Just showing JSON is not enough to be an answer (unless that was the question).

Answer (score 0):

Following on Robert G's suggestions, I ended up instantiating a dedicated logger from the Python native logging library, asking it to log json dumps. It works fine, without any need to involve GCloud's CLI or API, and it registers jsonPayloads that can be used to generate metrics on GCP (my ultimate goal). Only, I could not find a way to incorporate the desired info to the existing logs, they are being displayed as a new entry, but that is good enough to my purpose.